# Cannot connect to external MS SQL Server Database via GoDaddy Shared Windows Hosting (IP Whitelist not working)

Tags: php, sql-server, plesk, shared-hosting, mssql-jdbc

I am attempting to connect to an external MSSQL database using PHP on my Wordpress website. I am using Shared Plesk Windows hosting on GoDaddy with a set Dedicated IP.

The issue seems to be related to the external MSSQL firewall - I have provided my dedicated IP for the database to whitelist but it still doesn't allow a connection. I have asked the MSSQL company to temporarily drop the firewall and the connection is successful.

I have pinged my server and checked the IP using online tools and they both return the same IP so I am confident the IP is correct.

My question is - will be dedicated IP being using on my Shared Windows Plesk hosting be the 'true' external IP of the server? Or is it still some sort of proxy?

GoDaddy support are adamant the dedicated IP I am using is the external IP which the outside world sees. Could the issue be to do with ports? The MSSQL database is open to my IP on port 1433. Would this be a different port if I am connecting to the MSSQL via PHP on GoDaddy Plesk?

Thanks all, I look forward to your feedback as GoDaddy support have me pulling my hair out at the moment!

Comment: you could try disabling the firewall temporarily, establish a connection to sql server and check sys.dm_exec_connections.

Comment: If you have an instance name in your connection string then you'll need udp/1434 open to connect to the SQL Browser Server in addition to whatever tcp port your particular instance is listening on.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - I am going to contact the database support team now and try both of these points. I will report back when I have a reply! Much appriciated.

Comment: It's usually possible to avoid using instance names (and so avoid the SQL Browser Service) if you already know the port number, e.g.: instead of `server=some.example.com\MSSQLSERVER;` you can use the port number directly with `server=some.example.com,1433;`.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the instance name didn't work. This is the full server string if you are interested: $server = "HostIP\MSSQLSERVER,1433";